# Where can I obtain downloadable Minecraft sounds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know where one could obtain Minecraft sounds?

Particulary - I need the creeper fuse/expl. sound, I'd like to put it as my cellphone ringtone to creep out my fellow Minecrafters.

I guess any format will do.

Comment: ...But the game has terrible sound effects...

Comment: @GnomeSlice - lol? what does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sounds are stored in %appdata%\.minecraft\resources. They're in ogg format, so if you need to convert them, you could use something like this online converter: [media.io](http://media.io/)

I think the creeper fuse sounds are in newsound\mob (creeper1.ogg to creeper4.ogg). The explode sound is in random (explode.ogg).

Comment: Android phones can play .ogg natively (all the other ringtones are in that format), so you shouldn't need to convert it if you're using an Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you go in the Minecraft folder you can go into `/sounds` and use that folder to find them.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE mesh! Unfortunately, your answer is not helpful in the current form. Do you mean the _Minecraft_ application folder or the _Minecraft_ user data folder? Does anything need to be done to get the sounds out (e.g. archive extraction)? Be more specific and you will likely get your answer upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to %appdata%/.minecraft/resources/random. Select fuse, see if that works. Except I don't really know how you'll get it to be your ringtone.